# How to access elements in an array from another method?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in one method that takes in two lists of type `studentlist` and I need to access the array from the constructor method, `studentList` to get the size and the student numbers to compare between lists.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < L1.studentID.length-1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < L2.studentID.length-1; j++) {
        if (L1.studentID[i] = L2.studentID[j]) {
            num++; }}}
```

Most of the constructor, and not including the 2nd one for accessing lists in a file instead of randomly generated:

```
studentID=new int[size];
boolean[] usedID=new boolean[IDrange];
for (int i=0;i<IDrange;i++) usedID[i]=false;
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    int t;
    do {
    t=(int)(Math.random()*IDrange);
    } while (usedID[t]);
    usedID[t]=true;
    studentID[i]=t; }
```

Size (list.studentID.length or I could have used list.numberOfStudents which is built in) seems fine, but I'm having trouble with getting the elements of the array themselves.  I figure I could just do `list.studentID[i]` but I get a 'type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean'.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not L1.studentID[i] == L2.studentID[j]? //double '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
if (L1.studentID[i] = L2.studentID[j])
```

You are making an attribution of `L2.studentID[j]` to `L1.studentID[i]` and then passing the value of `L1.studentID[i]` to the `if`

The if in java expects explicittly a boolean value.

You either want to do:

```
if (L1.studentID[i] == L2.studentID[j])
```

or

```
if ((L1.studentID[i] = L2.studentID[j])!=0)
```

The code you currently have is the same as doing:

```
L1.studentID[i] = L2.studentID[j];
if (L1.studentID[i]){  <-- this won't work because L1.studentID[i] is an int and the if expects a boolean
...
```

Comment: Oh yea, completely forgot I had to do that!  Thanks everyone, thought it had something to do with the boolean in the constructor or something.

Answer (score 2):

> 'type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean'

You are getting an `int` because you are doing an assignment: `=` operator.
To compare two integers you need to use `==` operator.

Try with

```
if (L1.studentID[i] == L2.studentID[j]) {
```

and you'll get a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare them like this

```
if (L1.studentID[i] == L2.studentID[j])
```

Otherwise you're doing an attribution of L2 to L1.